# New column in dataset based em last value of item

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

    In [5]: df
    Out[5]: 
       A
    0  1
    1  2
    2  3
    3  4
    4  5
```

I want to add a new column in dataset based em last value of item, like this

| A | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |

I tryed to use apply with iloc, but it doesn't worked

Can you help

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. You could use `shift` function to get the new column which will move all elements of given column into new column with a NaN in first element.

```
import pandas as pd
df['New_Col'] = df['A'].shift()
```

***OR***

In case you would like to fill NaNs with zeros then try following, approach is same as above for this one too.

```
import pandas as pd
df['New_Col'] = df['A'].shift().fillna(0)
```

Comment: That's right RavinderSingh13, thank you very much